# ScrollY/ScrollTop doesn't work when height of html and body is 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `height: 100%` and `overflow: auto` on `html`/`body` to fix a scroll bug on Chrome. However `ScrollY`/`ScrollTop` always return 0 now. Is there any way to check scroll position in this case?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="top-nav">
            <div class="scroll-wrapper">
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;

    body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;

        .wrapper {
            .top-nav {
                z-index: 999;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
            }
            .scroll-wrapper {
                padding-top: 45px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JS:

```
    // Add style to top-nav when scrolling down

    $('.wrapper').scroll(function () {
        if (window.scrollY > 0)                        //always 0
        if ($('.wrapper')[0].scrollTop > 0)   
        if ($('.scroll-wrapper')[0].scrollTop > 0)
    }
```

Comment: Hopefully that's not the real CSS.... jk. Can you share your HTML too?

Comment: updated my HTML

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

It appears your issue actually steams from both `html` and `html body` having `overflow: scroll`.

Try removing one of those CSS rules and see if your initial problem is still solved.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    /* overflow: auto; */

    body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;

       /* ... */

    }
}
```

You also need to change your javascript to check for document scrolling and not the wrapper.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop)
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0) {
        // Perform Action
    }
})
```

Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks Jason. For some reason I have to add `height: 100%` and `overflow: auto` to both html and body. I tried `document.body.scrollTop`, however it still always returns 0.

Comment: Did you fix this @vincentf